# Vscode показывает предупреждения flake8 как ошибки

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, linter, flake8

[image: Скриншот из vscode c ошибками]

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы некоторые из ошибок flake8 отображались как предупреждения. Например, E501 считается ошибкой, но никак не влияет на работу кода.
Но везде пишут только про то, как сделать игнорирование. Использование других линтеров мне так же не подходит, они не видят нужные мне методы flask-sqlalchemy или не видят некоторые ошибки в коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В официальной документации vscode я нашёл такое решение:
В настройках vscode меняем python.linting.flake8CategorySeverity.E на Warning